# Trying to run a clip_analysis for ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, buffer, clip

Trying to run a clip_analysis for a buffer analysis I just wrote but I keep getting an TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Not sure what I need to do to fix it and be able to run the buffer_analysis first and then the clip_analysis.

Script I have now is

```
for i in range(len(cities)):
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sites[i]+'.shp', sites[i]+'_Buffer3000.shp','3000')
print 'site buffered to',i,'buffer 3000'
arcpy.Clip_analysis(openSpace,i+'.shp', i+'_OpenSpace.shp')
print 'open space clipped to',i,'city limits'
```

The goal is to buffer the sites around the cities feature class and then clip the openSpace to the newly created buffers.

Also both analysis need to be run in the same for loop

Comment: What happens when you run this?  When I do to try and test it I get an indentation error and when I fix that I get `NameError: name 'cities' is not defined`.  Please review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312 for some tips on what is expected in a code snippet.  Please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  We are happy to try and help debug well-presented code snippets but GIS SE is not intended to be a "here's my code, fix it for me" site.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of concatenating strings in Python is with [string formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

```
i+'.shp'
```

which would be

```
str(i) + '.shp'
```

should, ideally, become

```
'{}.shp'.format(i)
```

It sometimes requires a few more characters to do this, but some QA/QC is built-in, in that all data types work. It doesn't matter if i refers to a list, tuple, string, float, whatever. It works. There is also some additional functionality that string formatting provides; [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

All that said, are you sure you didn't mean:

```
'{}.shp'.format(sites[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first fix you should probably look at is:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(str(sites[i])+'.shp', str(sites[i])+'_Buffer3000.shp','3000')
```

but this is likely to lead you into trouble because shapefile names should not start with a number.